# Where is the full list of Fillings for In re: Enforcement of Election Laws in the Georgia State Court?

Tags: georgia

## Background

One of the many suits that the Republican party and Donald Trump filed after November 3rd in Georgia was [In re: enforcement of election laws and securing ballots cast or received after 7:00pm on November 3, 2020](https://www.democracydocket.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/45/2020/11/Petition-to-Enforce-Election-Law.pdf)
.  I found text of the petition linked above as well as the [judge's dismissal](https://www.democracydocket.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/45/2020/11/Order.pdf), but this portion of the case mentioned on [Buzzfeed](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/zoetillman/trump-false-claims-election-judges-reject-court-challenges) was a part that I could not find documentation for:

> A judge in Chatham County, Georgia, which includes Savannah, dismissed a Trump campaign lawsuit on Thursday that attempted to sow doubt about whether election officials were properly setting aside absentee ballots that arrived after the state’s Election Day deadline. The campaign presented two witnesses who said they were worried about a break in the chain of custody for 53 ballots. Under questioning by the county’s lawyer, they admitted they didn’t have evidence that those ballots had arrived late, however. A county official testified that the ballots had, in fact, arrived on time and were handled separately because they needed to be specially checked and entered into a computer system.

I just wanted to see the more detailed reasonings that the Judge dismissed the case based on the affidavit attached and the corresponding process of the court after the petition.

## Question

Where can I find the detailed documentation for In re: Enforcement of Election Laws in the Georgia State Court?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clerk of the [Superior Court of Chatham County in Georgia](https://courts.chathamcountyga.gov/Superior/CourtClerk) has a registry of actions for each case.

Unlike the federal courts, whose filings are available online via the PACER system, most states do not make the registries of actions of state courts fully available to the general public via the Internet. Typically, one must either be an attorney with an account in their system, or ask the clerk's office for information on a case by case basis. This appears to be the case in Georgia. This is a public record, but that doesn't mean that it is easily available online, and there may be a research or printing fee that must be paid to obtain it.

Another way to obtain it would be to contact one of the law firms that represents someone in the case and ask if they would be willing to provide this record to you. You could also consider contacting the reporter whose case references the material who may have already done this and may be more willing to share this information.